How can I fix anchor link offsets for fixed header to work in Mozilla Firefox (non-ESR version)?
This CSS works - in most browsers - to create an offset when linking to anchors on a website that has a fixed header:
`    a.macanchor::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 215px;
    margin-top: -215px;
    visibility: hidden;
}`

Unfortunately, this code does not work correctly - or consistently - in non-ESR versions of Mozilla Firefox.  Sometimes the link goes to the right place, but usually the target is too far down and you need to keep scrolling to reach the intended target.
Does anyone know how to get this to work correctly in non-ESR Firefox?
Related question: How can I write a media query that targets non-ESR Firefox?
I tried adding a  tag within the page to create an offset so that the link target is not obscured by the fixed header.  It works on most browsers - but not the non-ESR version of Mozilla Firefox.
Thanks,
Eddie

can you please include a complete minimal working example?

It's difficult to create a minimal example because this problem is occurring in a Joomla! website with an embedded template and various assigned modules, plugins, etc.  I'm not sure how to recreate this as a minimal working example,  You can see the problem live if you visit https://testsite4.sas.rutgers.edu/2024-2029-strategic-plan with the non-ESR version of Firefox.
